# Flutter Plugin containing static library (.a File) is not linked correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter Plugin, which for iOS uses a static library (.a file). If I add the plugin to my pubspec.yaml and install it via `flutter pub get`, it installs a pod, which I can see in my app`s XCode project, **everything correct so far**.

pubspec.yaml:

```
  XXX_flutter:
    git:
      url: git@gitlab:XXX-solutions/app/flutter/plugin_XXX.git
      ref: "develop"
```

However if I build the app, I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>         "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XXX", referenced from:
>             objc-class-ref in XXX.o
>       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

In the XCode workspace, in the Pods project, if I select the XXX pod, I can add the .a file manually to "Pod Project -> TARGETS XXX -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries". This *would solve* the problem, but I had to do it any time I do a flutter clean, pub upgrade, team member checks out project etc.. since the Pods are not under source control, so this **solution is not good**.

I tried to add the .a file to my app`s project "Link Binary With Libraries", but this didnt fix it. I have no idea how to solve this.

Note: The library is proprietary software, so it´s blacked out because I think the developers dont want to see problems issued with their software. The plugin itself is just Flutter wrappers for the library and is written by our team.

[image: XCode Workspace]

Comment: If it's just a `.a` have you considered using `dart:ffi` to access its methods rather than using a traditional plugin?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We will consider, but actually we were hoping to just fix the linking error.

Comment: Hey, I am also struggling with this. Did you solve the issue? If so, if you could answer your question it would be helpful for others too :)

Comment: Also having the same problem

Comment: I have same problem. Anyone came up with solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the static lib you are using isn't compiled for arm64 devices, so you need to exclude this architecture from your build. See pic.

*Note: it's only on release, you may have issues excluding arm64 for debug if you have an M1/M2 mac and using simulators.

You can release to App Store for ios devices with arm64 excluded with no issue.

Alternatively, you could include a version of your static lib that is compiled for arm64 arc.

[image]